# Indexing and searching related objects with haystack

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm pretty new to search implementation, bear with me while I'm learning!

So my pet project is a recipe site and each recipe can have n steps. the model looks something like:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    hotness = models.ForeignKey(Hotness)
    recipe_diet = models.ManyToManyField(DietType)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through="RecipeIngredient")

class DietType(models.Model):
    diet_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    quantifier = models.ForeignKey(Quantifier)
    quantity = models.FloatField()

class RecipeSteps(models.Model):
    step_number = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

(shortened for brevity)

I want to index all of it: Recipe, RecipeIngredient, DietType and Steps...
The DietType and RecipeIngredient seem to be working fine, but the Steps are not. I assume this has to do with the usage of 'RelatedSearchQuerySet' ?

Here is my search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from recipes.models import Recipe

class RecipeIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    ingredients = indexes.MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True)
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
    hotness = indexes.CharField(model_attr='hotness')
    diet_type = indexes.MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True)
    recipesteps = indexes.MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True)

    def prepare_steps(self, object):
        return [step.description for step in object.recipesteps.all()]

    def get_model(self):
        return Recipe

    def load_all_queryset(self):
        # Pull all objects related to the Note in search results.
        return Recipe.objects.all().select_related()
```

Here is the template recipe_text.txt:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.cuisine }}
{% for ingr in object.ingredients.all %}
  {{ ingr.title }}
{% endfor %}
{{ object.description }}
{% for dt in object.recipe_diet.all %}
  {{ dt.diet_type }}
{% endfor %}
{{ object.user }}
{{ object.hotness }}
{% for step in object.recipesteps.all %}
  {{ step.description }}
{% endfor %}
{{ object.body }}
```

I can search ingredients, title, description, diet type - everything works, except the RecipeSteps.

Finally, I'm making queries through the shell only at the moment:

```
#producing results:
sq = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='onion') #ingredient
sq = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='bolognese') #title
sq = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='bologna') #description
#not producing any results:
sq = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='chop') #step
sq = RelatedSearchQuerySet().filter(content='chop').load_all() #assuming this does the expanded search
```

Any idea?

Comment: I want to be able to get recipes that contain a step that matches a search query. IE: I want to search the steps themselves but get the recipe back.

Comment: Does `RecipeSteps` have its own index?

Comment: No, I haven't indexed this for search at all yet. Is that the key?

Comment: I am fairly sure that will set you right.

Comment: Was it any help?

Answer (score 4):

I have identified two issues:

1. The name `prepare_steps` in your `RecipeIndex` is wrong it should be `prepare_{field_name}` so change it to `prepare_recipesteps`
2. You are trying to access related steps `object.recipesteps.all` objects `recipe_text.txt` in a wrong way, it should be `object.recipesteps_set.all`. Or keep using `recipesteps` but add this as a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in `RecipeSteps` model for `ForeignKey` Recipe e.g.

   ```
   class RecipeSteps(models.Model):
       # //
       recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='recipesteps')
   ```